# Jquery Draggable containment string value

Tags: jquery-ui

All, I know the `Draggable` containment option can be set string values with these follow.

`Parent`(Constrains dragging to within the bounds of parent element of current element),`window` and `document`.

but I don't know what is the difference between the `window` and `document` values. and I didn't found any api document for this two values. please help me understand it .thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all boils down to the [difference between `window` and `document`](http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/). When you set the `containment` of a draggable, jQuery uses the `width` and `height` properties of either of them to determine its bounds, as [the sources](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/ui.draggable.js?r=3103) show (formatted for readability):

```
if(o.containment == 'document' || o.containment == 'window') this.containment = [
    0 - this.offset.relative.left - this.offset.parent.left,
    0 - this.offset.relative.top - this.offset.parent.top,
    $(o.containment == 'document' ? document : window).width() -
        this.helperProportions.width - this.margins.left,
    ($(o.containment == 'document' ? document : window).height() ||
        document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) - this.helperProportions.height -
        this.margins.top
];
```

If there are no `iframe`s, then I believe both dimensions will be the same, otherwise, things can be a little different (though I'm unsure if jQuery supports drag and drop between `iframe`s, even if from the same origin).

Comment: Thanks,mgibsonbr, I believe in the most of cases these two settings are the same. anyway, I think the `parent` or `array` setting is enough for usage.